# What is the state of the art in socket handling with Java 1.7?

Tags: java, sockets, try-with-resources

I'm searching for the best pattern to implement client/server socket communication using appropriate features of Java 1.7 (*try-with-resources*). It must be assured all threads and resources are closed and released completely. [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)/[Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) items should be considered as well as simple debugability (only one statement in each line).

Any feedback or discussion would be appreciated.

## First approach

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.junit.Test;

public final class ThreadedServerTest1 {
    private static final class ThreadedServer implements Runnable {
        private final Socket socket;

        ThreadedServer(final Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public static void main(final String arguments[]) {
            final int port = arguments.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(arguments[0]) : 9999;
            try (final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
                while (true) {
                    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    final ThreadedServer server = new ThreadedServer(socket);
                    final Thread thread = new Thread(server);
                    thread.start();
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // @formatter:off
            try (
                // See http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7027552 and
                // http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7013420:
                final Socket socket = this.socket;
                final InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                final OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                final OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            ) {
                // @formatter:on
                final String request = bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(String.format("Received from client: %s", request));
                printWriter.println("Hello client!");
                printWriter.flush();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class Client {
        public static void main(final String arguments[]) {
            final int port = arguments.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(arguments[0]) : 9999;
            try {
                final InetAddress loopbackAddress = InetAddress.getByName(null);
                // @formatter:off
                try (
                    final Socket socket = new Socket(loopbackAddress, port);
                    final OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    final OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                    final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                    final InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                    final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
                ) {
                    // @formatter:on
                    printWriter.println("Hello server!");
                    printWriter.flush();
                    final String answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    System.out.println(String.format("Answer from server: %s", answer));
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final String[] arguments = new String[] { "9999" };
        final Thread tread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ThreadedServer.main(arguments);
            };
        };
        tread.start();
        Client.main(arguments);
    }
}
```

Pros:

- Less lines of code

Cons:

- Large try-with-resources blocks (no support in Eclipse formatter)
- Second `Socke`t instance needed to use try-with-resources
- Deep nesting because of the `UnknownHostException` from `InetAddress#getByName(null)`

## Second approach

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.junit.Test;

public final class ThreadedServerTest2 {
    private static final class Connection implements AutoCloseable {
        final Socket socket;
        final InputStream inputStream;
        final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        final OutputStream outputStream;
        final OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter;
        final PrintWriter printWriter;

        private Connection(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
            this.socket = socket;
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        }

        static Connection serverConnection(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
            return new Connection(socket);
        }

        static Connection clientConnection(final String hostname, final int port) throws IOException {
            final InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
            final Socket socket = new Socket(inetAddress, port);
            return new Connection(socket);
        }

        static Connection localhostCientConnection(final int port) throws IOException {
            return clientConnection(null, port);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            closeAndIgnoreException(printWriter, outputStreamWriter, outputStream, bufferedReader, inputStreamReader, inputStream, socket);
        }

        private void closeAndIgnoreException(final AutoCloseable... closeables) {
            for (final AutoCloseable closeable : closeables) {
                try {
                    closeable.close();
                } catch (final Exception ignore) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class ThreadedServer implements Runnable {
        private final Socket socket;

        private ThreadedServer(final Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public static void main(final String arguments[]) {
            final int port = arguments.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(arguments[0]) : 9999;
            try (final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
                while (true) {
                    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    final ThreadedServer server = new ThreadedServer(socket);
                    final Thread thread = new Thread(server);
                    thread.start();
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (Connection connection = Connection.serverConnection(socket)) {
                final String request = connection.bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(String.format("Received from client: %s", request));
                connection.printWriter.println("Hello client!");
                connection.printWriter.flush();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class Client {
        public static void main(final String arguments[]) {
            final int port = arguments.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(arguments[0]) : 9999;
            try (Connection connection = Connection.localhostCientConnection(port)) {
                connection.printWriter.println("Hello server!");
                connection.printWriter.flush();
                final String answer = connection.bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(String.format("Answer from server: %s", answer));
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final String[] arguments = new String[] { "9999" };
        final Thread tread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ThreadedServer.main(arguments);
            };
        };
        tread.start();
        Client.main(arguments);
    }
}
```

Pros:

- Clean and readable try-with-resources blocks
- Support in Eclipse formatter

Cons:

- More lines of code
- Own `Connection` class needed
- Closing the `AutoCloseable` instances in the `Connection` class may be forgotten (error prone)

Do you have feedback or additions to the pros and cons? Are there more weaknesses?

## Third approach

That's the result of the discussion below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.junit.Test;

public final class ThreadedServerTest3 {
    private static final class ThreadedServer implements Runnable {
        private final Socket socket;

        private ThreadedServer(final Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public static void main(final String arguments[]) {
            final int port = arguments.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(arguments[0]) : 9999;
            try (final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
                while (true) {
                    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    final ThreadedServer server = new ThreadedServer(socket);
                    final Thread thread = new Thread(server);
                    thread.start();
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // @formatter:off
            try (
                // See http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7027552 and
                // http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7013420:
                Socket socket = this.socket;
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            ) {
                // @formatter:on
                final String request = bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(String.format("Received from client: %s", request));
                printWriter.println("Hello client!");
                printWriter.flush();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class Client {
        public static void main(final String arguments[]) {
            final int port = arguments.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(arguments[0]) : 9999;
            // @formatter:off
            try (
                Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(null), port);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))
            ) {
                // @formatter:on
                printWriter.println("Hello server!");
                printWriter.flush();
                final String answer = bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(String.format("Answer from server: %s", answer));
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final String[] arguments = new String[] { "9999" };
        final Thread tread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ThreadedServer.main(arguments);
            };
        };
        tread.start();
        Client.main(arguments);
    }
}
```

Pros:

- Less lines of code
- No to complex and mostly readable try-with-resources blocks
- No ingored exceptions

Cons:

- No support in Eclipse formatter
- Some violations of the rule "only one statements in each line" (simple debugability)

Comment: Very well constructed question, but its better suited to [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: IMHO using the `final` modifier for method arguments is a bit overkill and lessens the readability of the code.

Answer (score 8):

- The final modifier is redundant in a try-with-resources, as the spec [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

  > A resource declared in a ResourceSpecification is implicitly declared final (§4.12.4) if it is not explicitly declared final.
- closing a reader will also close the underlying stream, same for closing a writer. It is therefore not necessary to declare the intermediary streams as resources.
- your second approach incorrectly ignores exceptions thrown when closing the resources. Closing a stream flushes it, and if that doesn't suceed not all data will have been sent, which clearly warrants throwing an exception. In constrast, the try-with-resources statement does propagate exceptions thrown when closing (possibly as suppressed exceptions, see the spec for [details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1)).

Therefore, I recommend:

```
try (
    Socket socket = this.socket;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()))
) {
```

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. I added a third approach consider your recommendations.